# how to call optimizeAllocation to migrate vms in cloudsim

Tags: java, migration, cloud, virtual-machine, cloudsim

i m working on cloudsim to implement an genetic algorithm to find the optimal placement of vms in hosts.
in the begening i need to put vms randomly ( i created a class that extends from **VmAllocationPolicy** )
then i need to optimize vm allocation by migrating them to other hosts : i rode that i have to implement optimizeAllocation method inside my policy , i did it but i don't know how to execute it (optimizeAllocation)

Comment: I found the solution .
I called it from data center by : datacenter0.getallocationpolicy().optimizeallocation()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution . I called it from data center by :

datacenter0.getallocationpolicy().optimizeallocation()